# Difference between 2 solr queries

Tags: solr

What is the difference between running the following two solr queries. They seem to be giving me a different number of results.

```
  fq=field1:value1&fq=(field2:value21 OR field2:value22)
```

versus

```
  fq=field1:value1&fq=field2:value21 OR field2:value22
```

The first one gives me a larger result set whereas the second one gives me a smaller results set. Does the parentheses have any effect in this case? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this manual, for using Boolean operators in SOLR

```
http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/solr-and-boolean-operators/
```